# Почему нельзя обратиться к типу Window по его id?

Tags: qt, qml

Есть у меня вот такой пример с прямоугольником:

```
Rectangle {
     id: page
     width: 640
     height: 480
     color: "lightgray"

     Text {
         text: "Hello world!"
         anchors.horizontalCenter: page.horizontalCenter
     }
 }
```

Здесь видно, что внутри Text происходит обращение к вышестоящему Rectangle по id page. И происходит центрирование текста относительно прямоугольника. Все работает правильно.

Теперь делаем то же самое с Window:

```
Window {
    id: content
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        text: "Hello world!"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: content.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```

И видим, что обращение по id content не работает. Центрирования не происходит.

А если вместо id написать parent, то центрирование работает:

```
Window {
    id: content
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        text: "Hello world!"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```

То есть, по каким-то причинам для типа Window невозможно обращение через id.

Это что за ограничение такое? Как его обойти? Мне нужно к объекту Window обращаться по id, а не писать цепочки parent с учетом вложенности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что родителем вашего `Text` является не `Window`, а некоторый `Item`, который можно получить из `Window.contentItem`. Т.е., если Вы не хотите использовать `parent`, тогда используйте `content.contentItem.horizontalCenter`.

Как можно заметить в [документации](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window-members.html), у `Window` нет свойства `horizontalCenter`, т.к. `Window` является `QQuickWindow`, а не `QQuickItem` (и не наследуется от него).